# Is it possible to extract amenity shapefiles using a Google API?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-earth, google-maps-api, overpass-turbo

Is it possible to extract shapefiles by amenity using a Google API, similar to the way you can extract shapefiles using OpenStreetMaps/Overpass Turbo? I have had some accuracy issues using the OSM data, and I thought Google may be more reliable. As an example, let's say I want to search all Universities in a specified area- I'd want an output of university shapefiles with some correlating data such as the name of the university.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Just like with other similar services, Google Maps terms of use prohibit saving and caching their data. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996838/is-it-possible-to-store-google-maps-api-data-into-data-base/51996851